# Multiple Flask app api's via Nginx gateway on the same port 80 gives 502 error

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy

Tying to set up multiple flask API's via Nginx gateway (uwsgi) seems unable to add multiple locations / in the Nginx conf file. The authentication service seems working fine on port 80 but the streaming service always returns 502.

Structure (with docker files)
-authentication - It works fine
**-streaming - Gives 502  http://127.0.0.1/devapp/api/v1/home/list**
-ngix

Nginx config :

```
    server {
listen 80;

location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass authentication:8080;
}

location /devapp/ {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass streaming:8081;
} }
```

**uwsgi.ini:** (for the streaming module)

```
#Contains uwsgi configurations
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file= run.py
callable = app
socket = :8081
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chomod-socket = 660
vaccum = true
die-on-term = true
module = run
```

Nginx Log:

```
docker logs --tail=10 -f nginx
 2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
    2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
    2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
    2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
    2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
    2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
    2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
    2021/09/13 02:19:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
    2021/09/13 02:21:23 [error] 23#23: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET /devapp/api/v1/home/list HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://172.21.0.3:8081", host: "127.0.0.1"
    172.21.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2021:02:21:23 +0000] "GET /devapp/api/v1/home/list HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8" "-"
```

Comment: have you checked the nginx logs while trying to access streaming?

Comment: @eagr hmm nothing useful there it seems this is the output (updated the question)

Comment: the log says "Connection refused" so check for connectivity, are they in the same docker network? is the port in the firewall (on streaming)...?

Comment: @eagr both are on the same network and no firewall configured and I can connect to the authentication module